# Convert Vue.js project to ch5-file for a Crestron device

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I have an Interface for a Crestron Tablet as a vue.js project. But it needs to be converted into a CH5-file in order to be uploaded to the device.

I already managed to convert an html-file into a ch5-file using this documentation:
https://sdkcon78221.crestron.com/sdk/Crestron_HTML5UI/Content/Topics/UI-CH5-Archives.htm

But I wasn't able using webpack, to compress the vue.js-project.

Maybe there is a simpler way or a better documentation how to use webpack. I have very little knowledge of the Crestron Software solutions (Construct, VT Pro e, Contract Editor), but would any of these be useful for my case?

Thank you very much for your help ♥